# Why is node.js fetch giving a 'Bad Request' error?

Tags: node.js

I am getting a  400 error (bad request) from this POST:

```
siteData.myPost = async function (url, data) {
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    try {
        const response = await fetch(quilkinUrlBase() + url,options);
        return response.json();
    }
    catch (error) {
        qPopup.Alert("Error with web request: " + error);
    }
};
```

(the fetch address computes to "http://localhost:1337/UpdateSiteVisits").

This can't, of course,  convert 'response' to json because the response is a DOC containing the 400 error message.

in server.js I have the following callback definition for the URL specified in the fetch:

```
app.post("/UpdateSiteVisits", sites.updateVisits);
```

in the debugger, the code never reaches updateVisits().
I have a very similar construct with a GET:

```
app.get("/GetSitesForType/:type", sites.findByType);
```

which works fine, so I assume the problem is with the 'options' object (which the GET doesn't use). In the POST case the data is just an integer ID, and if I change the data format to plain text (instead of json), the post works fine.
If leave the format as json, and send an *object*, rather than a simple integer, the post also works fine. So it looks like the system just doesn't like converting a  single integer to json.

Comment: edit to ` 'Content-Type': 'application/json'` and `return await response.json();`

Comment: thanks for suggestion - but tried now, and no difference, still a 400 error

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send the integer as json, so instead of using the method like this:

```
siteData.myPost("UpdateSiteVisits", siteID)
```

I needed to use

```
siteData.myPost("UpdateSiteVisits", { siteId: siteID })
```

[ later ]
Please ignore my question and answer, I was just getting mixed up with types. Such is the result from me converting from strongly-typed C# to untyped javascript!